# MySql Server System Variables --max-seeks-for-key - Practical example

Tags: mysql, full-table-scan

I am going through documentation of MySql Indexes Optimization.

I found a setting --max-seeks-for-key=1000.I checked the "server system variables" of MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_seeks_for_key).
According to it

> "By setting this to a low value (say, 100), you can force MySQL to
>   prefer indexes instead of table scans"

.
What i understand from FULL TABLE SCAN is:

> When a query needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is
>   faster than working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk
>   seeks, even if not all the rows are needed for the query.

Therefore if MySQL is doing Full Table Scan which minimize disk seeks why would one use --max-seeks-for-key=1000 to prefer index scan which may increase disk seeks.

Here at the documentation [8.3.1.20 How to Avoid Full Table Scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html)s its  mentioned as a step to avoid full-scan: Start mysqld with the --max-seeks-for-key=1000

So I am curious to know if there is any practical and meaningful use of --max-seeks-for-key.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have a real query here executed by Magento, I am running MySQL *5.7*

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 
  main_table.entity_id
FROM catalog_category_flat_store_2 AS main_table
LEFT JOIN core_url_rewrite AS url_rewrite ON 
  url_rewrite.category_id = main_table.entity_id
  AND url_rewrite.is_system = 1
  AND url_rewrite.store_id = 2
  AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
WHERE main_table.include_in_menu = '1'
  AND main_table.is_active = '1'
  AND main_table.path LIKE '1/2/%'
ORDER BY main_table.position ASC
```

When I set `max_seeks_for_key` to `670` or lower, the query runs in 2 seconds. When the value is higher (very high by default), the query takes about **6 minutes**.

Yes, I know it's an awful query. I did not write it, it's created by the Magento e-commerce application framework.

I used *EXPLAIN* to find the difference. I see with the low `max_seeks_for_key` value it uses an index for the `core_url_rewrite` table. With a higher value it doesn't.

MySQL 5.6 **does** use an index for the same query without any changes to the configuration.

Extra context:
The `catalog_category_flat_store_2` table contains 732 records. The table `core_url_rewrite` is 1.8 Million records. The index is a non-unique index on the `category_id` field (the JOIN field) with a cardinality of 571. The result is 629 rows.

Don't forget to run `ANALYSE TABLE` to help MySQL take the correct decisions.

Comment: I'm curious why do you say `Yes, I know it's an awful query`. Can you explain?